# Yii2 Use variable in onCondition

Tags: php, yii2

Is that possible to use variable in the onCondition?

Here is the relation:

```
public function getMybook()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Book::className(), ['book_id' => 'idbook'])->onCondition(['user_id' => $user_id]);
}
```

I want to use it in joinWith like below:

```
$books = Books::find()->joinWith('myBook')->all();
```

But how do I send the user_id parameter into the onConditon? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use closure, for example:

```
return $this->hasOne(Book::className(), ['book_id' => 'idbook'])->andWhere('user_id = :user_id');


$user_id = 123;
$books = Books::find()->joinWith([
    'myBook' => function ($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->addParams([':user_id' => $user_id]);
    }
])->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can not use dynamic param in relation function. 
But why don't you use where condition:

```
$books = Books::find()->joinWith('myBook')->where(['myBook.user_id'=>$user_id])->all();
```

Comment: No, I need the sql to be select * from books left join mybook on books.id=mybook.id and userid=1 where something. If I use where clause, it will become select * from books left join mybook on books.id=mybook.id where userid=1, the result is not what I want.